# Black Screen with white underscore

Tags: boot

The problem appeard after i turned off ubuntu from the power off button of the computer ,I think there were some things going on . Now when i turn on my computer it starts but short after that i see a black screen with a white underscore blinking. I inserted a bootable usb with ubuntu , ended up partitioning de hard drives, installing the system and when i press ok on the message to restart the system so that the instalation be completed i  end up at the ssame white underscore blinking , doesn't goes any further .. When i try to enter bios by typing tab it seems like it's preparing some output is printed on the screen but it's stops and return to the black screen
.I can acces my system if i enter the boot priory section and choose the drive that is ubuntu installed on .. I've tried to install it on another partition and i get this:Sorry an error occured and it was not possible to install the bootloader at the spcified location how would you like to proceed choose a different device to install the bootloader on , continue without bootloader ,exit

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with GRUB, which is a program that lets you boot Ubuntu after powering on the computer. You usually only interact with it if you are dual booting with another operating system like Windows. Can you try running the boot repair program while using the live USB? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: While you're on that black screen with underscore, can you login by pressing Ctr+Alt+F1 (or any F key , 1 through 5) ? May be graphics driver as well